# Set locale on Heroku postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm using the Basic database plan at Heroku. This runs on Postgres 9.1 which has support for locales. I'm having issues with sorting in my app because the characters ÅÄÖ is not treated properly (as they should in Sweden).

The setting to set is `LC_COLLATE`, which handles string ordering. The problem is that I can't find any way to set this on Heroku. The databases that are created get `lc_collate=en_US.UTF-8`, but I need to set it to `sv_SE.UTF-8`.

This `LC_COLLATE` setting can't be changed when the database has been created, hence I can't change it through the psql console.

So, how can I set this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct that can't change the database's default collation; `LC_COLLATE` is an environment variable set on the Heroku database servers, which is both outside your control and already set before your database was created. You can, however, set the default collation for individual columns:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
    foo varchar COLLATE "sv_SE.UTF-8",
    bar varchar COLLATE "sv_SE.UTF-8"
);

ALTER TABLE existing_table ALTER COLUMN baz TYPE varchar COLLATE "sv_SE.UTF-8";
```

For more, see [22.2. Collation Support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html) in the PostgreSQL manual.

You may or may not need to `CREATE COLLATION` first. Additionally, all this depends on the Heroku database servers having the proper locale data installed -- although if they don't, you could probably ask nicely to get that deployed, since it wouldn't hurt anyone.

Failing that, you could of course run your own PostgreSQL instances in EC2, with whatever custom setup you want. That would require investing administration time, but honestly running 9.1 is pretty straightforward, even including streaming replication. Might even be cheaper too. The downside there is that keeping the database running becomes your problem instead of a problem for the Heroku ops team.

Comment: Wow, that's really annoying. PostgreSQL supports setting per-database collations via `CREATE DATABASE ... LC_CTYPE 'blah' LC_COLLATE 'blah'`; it sucks that Heroku doesn't expose that to users.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work to change the column collation. I did have to create the collation first though. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Finally. I have been struggling with this too long.
For me it didn't work with "sv-SE.UTF-8" but "sv-SE" only.

Using rails, I made a rake task to change the collation with following code:
----
namespace :setup do
  task :heroku_collation => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'ALTER TABLE municipalities ALTER COLUMN name TYPE varchar COLLATE "sv_SE";'
  end
end

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a migration that alters the collation of the concerned columns (like willglyn suggests):

```
class SetSwedishCollationForStores < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute 'ALTER TABLE stores ALTER COLUMN city  TYPE varchar COLLATE "sv_SE";' 
    execute 'ALTER TABLE stores ALTER COLUMN title TYPE varchar COLLATE "sv_SE";' 
  end
end
```