# ruby on rails' alphabetical order method doesn't place word boundary before "a"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I think this has something to do with Postgresql, because in a local sqlite3 database, I don't see the behavior.

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails 5 app with a postgresql DB. I'm using c9.io though, à la Hartl's Rails Tutorial, so locally I'm using a sqlite3 DB for development, then I'm pushing it up to Heroku for production. I know, not a good idea to have a different DB on the local. But I don't think I can run postgresql on c9. It's there, but I don't think I have the permissions. Anyhoo...

Let's say I have a class 'Book', with a field 'title'. I have 4 records with these titles:

```
"africa cloud"
"africa rain"
"african cloud"
"african rain"
```

In the rails console on Heroku, if I ask these to be ordered by title:

```
@books = Book.all.order(:title)
@books.each do |b|
  puts b.title
end
```

I get this, incorrect, order:

```
africa cloud
african cloud
african rain
africa rain
```

It treats the word boundary like it's not even there. Who orders alphabetically like that? But if I take the titles out, put them into their own array, then apply the .sort method on them, I get a correctly sorted list:

```
@titles = []
@books.each do |b|
  @titles << b.title
end
@titles.sort.each do |t|
  puts t
end

africa cloud
africa rain
african cloud
african rain
```

I sense that ruby does its method "sort" right, but the rails method "order" for postgresql is off somehow, like the regex rules are different under the hood. As I said before, this behavior doesn't show up in the local setup which is using the sqlite3 database.

So that's the background. I'd like to know an explanation for the behavior, and I'd to know how to override this behavior to get a properly alphabetized list on the production server.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534484/postgresql-incorrect-sorting, it might help you.

Comment: Yes, it's a collation / locale issue. c9.io has C.UTF-8 and Heroku is using en_US.UTF-8. A good example of this behavior is shown here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252419/unexpected-sort-order-in-en-us-utf-8-locale I think I need to set the locale in Heroku to C UTF-8 as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334986/set-locale-on-heroku-postgres